# Custom helper methods for Rails 3.2 Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, helper, helpermethods

I'm trying to access helper methods inside my migrations.  I can't seem to get anything to work when accomplishing something like this:

Migration File:

```
require File.expand_path('lib/migration_helper')
include MigrationHelper

class NewTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :new_table do |t|
      t.boolean :boolean
      safe_delete_methods
    end
  end
end
```

Migration helper in /lib directory

```
#Custom Methods available to Migrations

module MigrationHelper
   def safe_delete_methods
     return 
       t.boolean :deleted, :default => 0, :null => false
       t.integer :deleted_by, :default => 0, :null => false
       t.datetime :deleted_at
   end
end
```

Thank you for any answers

Comment: Figured it out:  safe_delete_methods(t), and take out the return...neat way to add helper methods to migrations, even the create_table method/object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module MigrationHelper

 def safe_delete_methods

   t.boolean :deleted, :default => 0, :null => false
   t.integer :deleted_by, :default => 0, :null => false
   t.datetime :deleted_at


 end

end
```

cann't use return before the code.